# When to use NextJS API Routes?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jamstack

I do not understand what extra functionality do `/api/` routes have over `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps`.

I have seen few examples, where people like to make `HTTP GET` requests using getStaticProps and getServerSideProps and use `/api/` route to make `PUT PATCH DELETE` requests.

Is there any official document on best practices on what to use for different use cases?

Answer (score 3):

You use `/api/` routes from the front end of your app. That means while your application is running and the page is already loaded. Let's say you have a dashboard page, and you are trying to display always fresh data. In that case, you would constantly hit your **api** routes to get the new data.

Also for example, if you have a `todo` app when the user saves a new todo task, you would post a request to `api/todo` to save the todo to the database.